# Why is the `%pa` printk format specifier not being recognized for `resource_size_t` type?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

When compiling my module, I get this warning:

```
# make modules
  CC [M]  /jriskhome/repos/module/my_module.o
/jriskhome/repos/module/my_module.c: In function ‘_pci_probe’:
/jriskhome/repos/module/my_module.c:882:3: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 7 has type ‘resource_size_t’ [-Wformat=]
   pr_info("Mapped Bar   %d: %p -> %pa (%pa)", bar_number, BAR, pci_resource_start(dev, bar_number), pci_resource_len(dev, bar_number));
   ^
/jriskhome/repos/module/my_module.c:882:3: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 8 has type ‘resource_size_t’ [-Wformat=]
```

I consulted this: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/printk-formats.txt?v=3.10
 and it looks right to me.  Kernel and compiler version are:

```
# uname -r
3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64
#  gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I can cast it, but was wondering why the format specifier isn't being accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation you pointed to:

> For printing a phys_addr_t type (and its derivatives, such as resource_size_t) which can vary based on build options, regardless of the width of the CPU data path. **Passed by reference.**

You need to pass a pointer to your value, rather than the value itself. I assume that this twist is necessary exactly in order to achieve the aforementioned independence from the current build options.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it would be something simple.